# Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 0W

Tags: pi-zero, windows-iot, windows

**Is it possible to install Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry Pi 0W?**

I know you can edit `recovery.cmdline` in the NOOBS directory to show all, but I do not know if the OS will work well with Raspberry Pi 0W?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

Win10 IoT only works on RPi2B & RPi3B.
There's a beta version for RPi3B+.

There's no version for any of the RPi4B models.